# Writing and closing Notepad++ using speech recognition libraries

Tags: c#, speech-recognition, voice-recognition

I'm trying to write code that will open Notepad++, write to a file, and close it afterward. My code is included below. I'm totally new to C#. Is there any library or way to do this?

```
// Button Reference
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (button1.Text.Equals("Enable Voice Control"))
    {
        button1.Text = "Stop Voice Control";
        recEngine.RecognizeAsync(RecognizeMode.Multiple);
    }
    else
    {
        button1.Text = "Enable Voice Control";
        recEngine.RecognizeAsyncStop();
    }
}        

public void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Choices commands = new Choices();
    commands.Add(myCommands);
    GrammarBuilder gBuilder = new GrammarBuilder();
    gBuilder.Append(commands);
    Grammar grammar = new Grammar(gBuilder);

    recEngine.LoadGrammarAsync(grammar);
    recEngine.SetInputToDefaultAudioDevice();
    recEngine.SpeechRecognized += recEngine_SpeechRecognized;
}

void recEngine_SpeechRecognized(object sender, SpeechRecognizedEventArgs e)
{
    Process cmd = new Process();
    cmd.StartInfo.FileName = @"notepad++.exe" ;
    //cmd.StartInfo.Arguments =@"\Write.txt";
    cmd.Start();
    cmd.CloseMainWindow();
    cmd.WaitForExit();
    cmd.Refresh();

    //if (cmd.StandardError != null)
    //Console.WriteLine(cmd.StandardError.ReadToEnd());

    var result = e.Result;
    var i = 0;
    foreach (var command in myCommands)
    {
        if (command.StartsWith("close"))
        {
            this.Close();
            //cmd.StartInfo.FileName = @"notepad++";
            cmd.Kill();
        }
        if (command.StartsWith("--") || command == string.Empty) continue;  // Skip commentBlocks and skipEmptylines
        var parts = command.Split(new char[] { '|' }); // Split the lines
        i++;
        if (command.Equals(result.Text))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Command is  {0}: {1}", i, command);
            break;
        }
    }
}

private void richTextBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
}
```

Comment: just write using ````File  Api```` if you want write ````.txt```` file

Comment: http://csharp.net-tutorials.com/file-handling/reading-and-writing/

Comment: Trying to automate another process is a pretty popular newbie project.  It is not a good one, this kind of code is never simple and little will be learned.  You'll do it right if you learn how to use the System.Windows.Automation namespace.  But consider to move on, you want to write and control your own programs first.  This project can wait.

Comment: @Hans passnt thanks for the input

Answer (score 0):

You need not open notepad and write to file. You can do it programmarically.

```
// Create a file to write to.
string createText = "Hello and Welcome" + Environment.NewLine;
File.WriteAllText(path, createText);

// Open the file to read from.
string readText = File.ReadAllText(path);
```

Comment: I want to open the Textfile through speech and also write in the opened text pad through speech

Answer (score -1):

You can use the below code to close the notepad:

```
Process[] processes = Process.GetProcessesByName("notepad");
foreach (var process in processes)
{
    process.Kill();
}
```

It will close all instances of notepad. So better be sure the notepads are only that of yours (opened by your speech recognition program)

If you actually do not want to open notepad and your requirement is just to capture text and write to file programatically, then use the below code:

```
// Create a file to write to.
string createText = "Hello World"; // Replace with voice captured text
File.WriteAllText(path, createText);

// Open the file to read from.
string readText = File.ReadAllText(path);
```

Comment: Since OP starts process himself there is not need to search for process instance. And this answer is not complete without part to insert text (the question shouldn't be attempted to answer and rather closed as broad in my opinion).

Comment: @Nithish. If you are sure you need to open notepad and enter text to actually automate the simulation of human interaction, then this is the option. If your requirement is only to capture the voice text and write to file, please refer my answer for writing to file programatically.